# Clearing Combo Box in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have two ComboBox in a macro-enabled powerpoint presentation. These Combobox represent a start-date and an end-date. The following piece of code clears the combobox, but not if the presentation opens with dates already present. So let's say you open the power point presentation, and the dates from when the presentation was previously given were still in the Combobox, if I try to apply this code...nothing happens. But if I adjust the dates in the combobox and apply the code again, it works and the combobox's are cleared. Strange! Any ideas?

```
Dim j As Long
Dim cb As Object

For j = 1 To 2
Set cb = Slide1.Shapes("ComboBox" & j).OLEFormat.Object
cb.Clear
Next j

'Clean up
 Set cb = Nothing
```

Thanks

Comment: how is this being called? If it is in a click event it will not clear until a selection is made in which case you need to look at tying to a different event to clear both initially.

Comment: That must be the reason. Thanks. So, best to clear when the combo box is opened?

Comment: How would you do that in Power point? Same as excel?

Comment: not sure i understand.When I use these in Excel, I tie them to a worksheet_activate to clear them when on the appropriate sheet.  I am just looking up the powerpoint events to see which might work, hang on....

Comment: sorry, I meant when power point presentation is opened...

Comment: You could or might be able to use this http://officeoneonline.com/vba/run_macro_at_slide.html You may have to fiddle to find the right event. On open sounds good.  I don't know if the link I gave only triggers during a slide show.

Comment: presentation open looks good from this http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

Comment: am trying:  Private Sub App_PresentationOpen(ByVal Pres As Presentation)
With Pres
    .Slide1.Shapes("ComboBox" & 1).OLEFormat.Object.Clear
End With   
with no luck...what should I set?     
End Sub

Comment: Apparently you can only use PresentationOpen event with an add - in.   AM I correct in saying that?

Comment: could you set the code running after a few moments of the file being open? as I cant use add-in's

Comment: cheers, looking into clearing the boxs on closing atm

Comment: if you are lucky enough to have @StephenRindsberg view this at some point you will probably get a definitive answer. From the link i gave it looks like you have to either have an add-in or associate with a more common event like mouseover or potentially a button click. I tried the WithEvents but always needed to run an initialize sub first to make the events (defined in the eventClass, such as App_SlideSelectionChanged) responsive. Apologies, has me beat at present.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...very much appreciated. Is it allowed on this forum to message someone directly? Or is there someway of drawing the named experts attention to the question? Is it allowed?

Comment: I don't think so. It might be a case of hoping he will see the tag and view the question.

Comment: Is it such a problem that there are selections present at the start? You will be able to trigger clearing of the second combobox the moment the first is triggered through a selection change.

Comment: Given the amount of pain this is causing, it might not be an issue, but equally, it requires an extra explanation somewhere. Lets say someone other than myself is using the presentation, most ppl assume a blank slate (meaning empty combo boxes), right? Which, given the current situation is not possible...as you cant clear them.

Comment: Here is a help link which allows points you to other forums for ppt help: http://www.pptfaq.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it

Comment: omg...how about....cb.Value = ""

Comment: .Value="" seems to work?!?!

Comment: How are you setting that? You should use vbNullString rather than “” normally.

Comment: Is that still within the click event?

Comment: It is under the same click event, thanks for the vbNullstring advice

Comment: Test to see if that works first!

Comment: it does. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will clear the contents of ComboBox1 on Slide 1:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Clear
End Sub
```

Wn.View.Slide.SlideIndex will give you the current slide's index, so you can replace .Slides(1) with .Slides(Wn.View.Slide.SlideIndex) to work with whatever slide you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The following clears dates in a Combo box, whether that date was there from a previous presentation being run or the current user has input the dates and now wishes to clear them.

```
 Dim j As Long
 Dim cb As Object

  For j = 1 To 2
  Set cb = Slide1.Shapes("ComboBox" & j).OLEFormat.Object
  cb.Value = vbNullString
  Next j

  'Clean up
   Set cb = Nothing
```

Comment: It does not clear the Combo boxes as soon as the Power point presentation is open...sadly. But, you can clear the Combo boxes whatever

Comment: Cheers QHarr for you help today!

Comment: By "as soon as the PowerPoint presentation is open", do you mean when you open the PPTX file, or do you mean when you launch it into  slideshow view (or open a PPSX file, which opens in slideshow view automatically)?

Comment: See the answer I posted above